# Help with applying exception in preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, sanitization

Hello How can I can I allow only digit [^0-9] and a minus sign in front the digit. Example :
Valid = -1...-9, Invalid = --1-...

Comment: [^0-9] matches '*not* a digit from 0-9'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove every invalid character and check if the remaining has a valid format:

```
$cleaned = preg_replace('/[^-0-9]+/', '', $str);
if (preg_match('/^-?[0-9]+$/', $cleaned)) {
    // now valid
}
```

Ok, here’s another suggestion:

```
preg_replace('/.*?(-?\d+).*/', '$1', $str)
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I apply it it returns nothing: 
var_dump (preg_replace('/(^-?[0-9]+)?.*|^[^-0-9]+/','$1', '--$ ----matches-- 12--'));

//output string '' (length=0)

Comment: @jartaud: I withdrew my first suggestion.

Comment: the panorama is: Im wainting for a negative _GET variable which helps me with the JS go method. Now what I m trying to do is remove all chars except the minus sign ?get=--2'''#$%$%$ should be: ?get=-2

Comment: @At all, this: $1 is very important

Answer (score 1):

Should be as simple as...

```
preg_match('#^-?[0-9]$#', $input);
```

**Update**

```
preg_replace('#-\d#', $replacement, $input);
```

Comment: note the question mark makes the minus sign optional, if it's required just remove the question mark.

Comment: Thanks for your help, yes the sign is required and I only need one in front (-digit)

Comment: Thanks again, it keeps returning a lot of "-", I need only one in front the \d

Answer (score 1):

```
/^-\d+$/
```

or if minus is optional

```
/^-?\d+$/
```