# Cannot remove double quotes from string PHP

Tags: php, string

Have tried every solution here and still nothing.
This is var_dump **string(19) ""Example""**.
I just need to remove double quotes from name so **"Example"** should be **Example**
Tried with **trim, preg_replace, substr**.

I think that there is problem somewhere else but I dont have much experience with PHP so I am stuck.

Comment: `$string = trim($string, '"');`

Comment: I said that that solution doesnt work

Comment: Then your problem is somewhere in the code, and as you haven't provided any of your code we can't help you.... you may not have much experience, but surely you can appreciate that we can't fix what we can't see

Comment: The ***less*** the good people know, the ***more time*** it takes to provide you with a solution and comments will just continue to grow until we know exactly which animal(s) were dealing with here. Which in turn, you're asking us to take a blind shot at an invisible target. So, show your full code and the values that are going though there.

Comment: You've a few answers below; ask them. If none of those worked, then ^ that comment should be taken seriously. Let's leave the guesswork to the weather forecasters *shall we?* ;-)

Comment: *"I think that there is problem somewhere"* - Ya think?

Comment: I have tried to implement imdb scrapper so I can get tv show name but it seems that name is longer than expected

Comment: you're going to make me scream. Post your full code and stop making us all guess for crying outloud and wasting everyone's time.

Comment: Run `var_dump($string);` to show Us the string. There might be entitie not regular character.

Comment: Also name is double quotes so I think that this is problem but it cant be solved with any of the php functions (tried almost every solution for this kind of problem here on stackoverflow)

Comment: ok whatever. I'm out of this one, which I'm sure you're quite happy about.

Comment: string(27) ""Game of Thrones""

Comment: Sorry I have not provided any code. This is how title is taken : $arr['title'] = str_replace('"', '', trim($this->match('/<title>(IMDb \- )*(.*?) \(.*?<\/title>/ms', $html, 2)));

Comment: So a string length of 27 bytes for `""Game of Thrones""`.... that doesn't add up to me.... so the real question should be to work out what invisible characters there are in this string

Comment: So far I figured out that this should be encoding problem. This is var_dump when I get string in htmlspecialchars for **Marvel's Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.: Double Agent**        var_dump = **string(74) "&#x22;Marvel&#x27;s Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.: Double Agent&#x22;"**

Comment: It looks like the problem is that the double quotes are actually html enttities in the raw string. str_replace() or trim() the entity instead of " and let us know if that solves the problem.

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to say. Have tried every possible combination and still nothing. Its definitely something about html entities but I have tried htmlentities htmlspecialchars and many other functions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `trim($string, '&#x22;');`  and take some time to learn about [HTML entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).

What's happening is the double quotes are html entities, so as you've seen in var_dump the string is not `"Movie Title"` but `&x#22;Movie Title&x#22;`. There is no literal double quote in the string for the function to trim, so it fails. You need to trim the entity instead.

Comment: Already figured it out. Not solution for my problem, but good guides and thanks for understanding of complexity of my problem. I found solution here [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365874/help-with-applying-exception-in-preg-replace

Answer (score 5):

Here we go:

```
<?php
$str = '""Example""';
$str = str_replace('"', '', $str);
echo $str;
?>
```

You can even see [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/HGusl6).

Comment: Either the OP ran off without saying "thanks", or it hasn't worked or they haven't seen this. *Lovely, eh?* I've my money on the former.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: So have I. Who cares though :)

Comment: It's not like I didn't try neither; and not just "once" neither - *sigh*. Oh well, *"c'est la vie"*, I guess.

Comment: I said that problem isnt so simple because I have tried all possible string edit functions

Answer (score 3):

This worked:

`$string = trim(html_entity_decode($string),'"');`

Comment: Thank you! I searched and searched for this. Great solution for my situation because I am importing tab delimited data via text file into MySQL database via PDO and no other functions were removing the leading and trailing double-quotes for me, properly.

Comment: In retrospect, this was because of the order I was doing things in. I was using htmlspecialchars(striptags(trim($s))) before the str_replace or other functions. Had I trimmed first, I wouldn't have needed to decode the html entity. Still a great help!

Answer (score 1):

If

```
str_replace('"', '', $a)
```

does not work, maybe that is not a single double quote, but it's analogue, like ¨